# combine a table into a cell maintaining its structure

Tags: excel, multiple-tables

```
Form               Touch
SIM                Single SIM, GSM
Business Features  Push Mail
```

This is a sample of a table that I have in excel. Can i combine these 6 cells into one single cell and maintain the table structure ?

I need this to be done as I will be importing that particular cell into an application which has a embedded word editor and I need it to be imported as a table.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your data is in A1 thru B3.  In another cell, enter:

=A1 & " " & B1 & CHAR(10) & A2 & " " & B2 & CHAR(10) & A3 & " " & B3

Format the new cell with text wrapping.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works. The only issue is that i am not able to get the table lines between the rows and columns. Its getting displayed like how it is getting displayed here in stackoverflow i.e without the lines to shows its a table.